# Would a wildcard SSL Certificate work without a sub-domain?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, subdomain, wildcard

We have to update our SSL certificate for an other year with a new COMODORS certificate.

We've had a old certificate (GeoTrust) with ***.domain.ch** which is correct from the naming aspect but expired from the date.

Now we've falsely made one with ***domain.ch** without the first dot. This should be a wildchart certificate for our domain.ch. 
Will this work or can this be the problem for server not starting after this SSL certificate update?

Comment: Why has someone downvoted this question? 
I don't get it? What's wrong with the content of the question?

Comment: Whoever downvoted, could you kindly tell me what I should do that will match up to your perfect standard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it will not work. This certificate will match against wwwdomain.ch but not www.domain.ch. But, no public CA should issue such a certificate in the first place since you could this way impersonate foo-domain.ch etc, i.e. domains which don't belong to you.

Comment: So should I purchase again?

Comment: @UbxSD: If the certificate is really the wrong one then you cannot use it. But if the CA really issued a certificate which matches domains not owned by you (i.e. `*yourdomain.com` as you claim, it would be different though with `*sub.yourdomain.com` which does not match domains which don't belong to you) then this would be  a security issue of the CA. Anyway, if you need to spend money again or if you are able to discuss the problem with the CA and get a free or cheaper replacement is up to you and the CA policies.

Answer (score 0):

If this certificate is in a pipeline to get issue then it won't get issued. If got issued erroneously then you have to re-issue the certificate from the vendor or the CA as the *domain.ch won't work.

**can this be the problem for server not starting after this SSL certificate update?**
Server won't start as there is a mismatch in the domain name